# difference of complexity in ordering and sorting?

Tags: numpy, time-complexity

I'm trying to understand the complexity of numpy array indexing here.

Given a 1-d numpy array `A`. and `b = numpy.argsort(A)`

what's the difference in time compleixty between `np.sort(A)` vs `A[b]` ?

for `np.sort(A)`, it would be `O(n log (n))`, while `A[b]` should be `O(n)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood `argsort` does a sort, which again gives complexity `O(n log(n))`.
You can actually specify the algorithm [as described here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

To conclude, while only `A[b]` is linear you cannot use this to beat the general complexity of sorting, as you yet have to determine `b` (by sorting).

Comment: yeah, I'm aware of that, but I'm more interested in the complexity of `A[b]`, as stated in the question, `b` was given.

Comment: If space complexity is irrelevant, you can fill `C[i] = A[b[i]]` in linear time. If space is constant, elements of A have to be swapped in some fancy way, which might not be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple timing:

```
In [233]: x = np.random.random(100000)                                                               
In [234]: timeit np.sort(x)                                                                          
6.79 ms ± 21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [235]: timeit x[np.argsort(x)]                                                                    
8.42 ms ± 220 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [236]: %%timeit b = np.argsort(x) 
     ...: x[b] 
     ...:                                                                                           
235 µs ± 694 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [237]: timeit np.argsort(x)                                                                         
8.08 ms ± 15.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Timing only one size doesn't give O complexity, but it reveals the relative significance of the different steps.

If you don't need the `argsort`, then `sort` directly.  If you already have `b` use it rather than sorting again.

Comment: thanks! yeah i did the same thing, but still i need somehow use the big o notation for `A[b]` in some technical document, where i'm not exactly sure `O(n)` is correct or not.

Comment: A quick test with smaller `x` shows the `A[b]` is roughly `O(n)`.   It has to copy `b.shape` items from `A` to a new new array,   Details of that are buried in complex `c` code - determining the size of `b`, allocating the target space, using `c` pointer indexing to copy from one data buffer to the other.

Comment: In the real world, operations are a mix of times.  There's a setup time, operation time etc.  So it might be `a*O(1) + b*O(n) + ...`  For small arrays the setup time can dominate, for large ones the O(n) etc.  Also with very large arrays, memory management becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a visual comparison to see it better:

```
#sort
def m1(A,b):
  return np.sort(A)

#compute argsort and them index
def m2(A,b):
  return A[np.argsort(A)]

#index with precomputed argsort
def m3(A,b):
  return A[b]

A = [np.random.rand(n) for n in [10,100,1000,10000]]
```

Runtime on a log-log scale:

[image]